# How to change the padding above and below a SwiftUI Divider?

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetkit

Right now, I have a VStack containing a Text, a HStack which contains a few more Texts, and a Divider between them.  The problem is that the padding to the top and bottom of the Divider is too much on some smaller devices, making the result look odd.  How can I decrease this padding (i.e. make the Texts to the top and bottom appear closer to the line)?

Answer (score 59):

It is not a `Divider` reason, it is default spacing behavior of VStack, which applies different spacing between different subview types. To disable this make

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {  // or any other constant
```

and then apply any specific padding for any sub-view.